# Xerial SnappyError: pure-java snappy requires access to java.nio.Buffer raw address field

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, snappy

when running local Maven build in Java project, I'm getting following error:

```
org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [UNSUPPORTED_PLATFORM] pure-java snappy requires access to java.nio.Buffer raw address field
    at org.xerial.snappy.pure.UnsafeUtil.<clinit>(UnsafeUtil.java:49)
    at org.xerial.snappy.pure.SnappyRawCompressor.writeUncompressedLength(SnappyRawCompressor.java:408)
    at org.xerial.snappy.pure.SnappyRawCompressor.compress(SnappyRawCompressor.java:111)
    at org.xerial.snappy.pure.PureJavaSnappy.rawCompress(PureJavaSnappy.java:128)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.rawCompress(Snappy.java:424)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.compress(Snappy.java:105)
```

I've tried solution from https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/issues/322 but it didn't help..

My OS configuration:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Java: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
Maven: Apache Maven 3.6.3
Snappy-java lib: snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar
Snappy version from pom.xml: org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4
```

Comment: How did you resolve this ? 
I have been facing the same problem

Thanks

Comment: I've resolved this by running each time command sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp. It seems Snappy download some files to /tmp folder and can't execute them - and as a result above error is present